# Generating functions are functions?

Tags: functions, definition, generating-functions

On [this Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20a%20generating%20function,generating%20function%20of%20the%20sequence) page it says the following: "in fact, the generating function is not actually regarded as a function".

This comment is made only because we don't need convergence in a generating function?  I feel a bit confused, since for example, there are cases in which we must derive the generating function.  I would like to have a more formal idea of ​​this comment. Or it could be the case that Wikipedia is wrong

Comment: "Formal power series," are also sometimes what they are called. We don't require convergence, we don't require a lot of strict things usual functions need.

Comment: Sometimes it's useful to regard a generating function as a formal power series, and other times it's useful to regard a generating function as an actual function on some domain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In full generality a generating function is a [formal power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series), so can be thought of as just a sequence $a_n$ of, say, complex numbers. We think of this sequence as a "sum" $f(z) = \sum a_n z^n$ in some sense (and this can be made precise using a "$z$-adic metric") but $z$ is not actually a complex number and this sum is not actually being taken in the usual sense of an infinite sum of complex numbers.

Moreover, because $a_n$ is completely arbitrary this sum, if interpreted as an "actual sum" of complex numbers, need not converge for any nonzero value of $z$, so $f(z)$ does not *necessarily* have any interpretation as an "actual function" of the complex variable $z$. It *can* have such an interpretation for sufficiently small $z$ if the radius of convergence is positive, but the radius of convergence could be zero. For example, consider the generating function

$$f(z) = \sum n! z^n$$

of the factorials. The radius of convergence is zero, so $f(z)$ as an "actual sum" of complex numbers does not converge for any $z \neq 0$. However this is still a perfectly well-defined generating function and one can still ask and answer interesting questions about it. For example it has a (formal) logarithm

$$\log \sum n! z^n = z + \frac{3}{2} z^2 + \frac{13}{3} z^3 + \frac{71}{4} z^4 + \dots $$

whose coefficients count the number of subgroups of finite index in the free group $F_2$: see [this blog post](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2015/11/03/the-answer-to-the-puzzle/) for details.

In practice this distinction doesn't matter too much because most generating functions have positive radius of convergence.